# What type of test / research design is recommended for this analysis

Tags: operations-research

It is assumed that people are not seeking for help when they need to, therefore a program is implemented to teach them when to seek help. People can join the program voluntarily. I would like to study the effectiveness of the program one year after it implementation, *i.e.*, is there any significant difference between two groups (those who joined the program and those did not) in the way they seek.

1) I am using quantitative causal-comparative research design. Am i correct?

2) I am not sure what type of analysis should be use for this design. Paired t-test? But I do not have pre-data.

Answer (score 1):

Causal Comparative Research is common in educational and training/development studies to investigte the effectiveness training program. This design attempts to determine the impact of, say, a human resource development program. In your the case, the alternative hypothesis could be *People joining the program are more effective seeking help when needed*. So you are right with the first question.

As of the second question, you can use *t-test*, not paired obviously because you will not have paired cases.